# How to filter using jq array of strings which contains a specific value

Tags: jq

How do I filter using jq which contains string "edp-api-dev"

```
{
    "serviceArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234:service/splat-dev/abc-api-dev-ecs-abc-api-man-1920299",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234:service/edp-api-dev-ecs-edp-api-man-721g8a7d",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234:service/tsm-frontend-dev-ecs-tsm-frontend-man",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234:service/doc-svc-dev-ecs-doc-svc-man",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234:service/wwk-frontend-dev-ecs-wwk-frontend-man-8fea6a0b",
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:1234:service/xyaz-fsse-ecs-xyaz-fsse-man"
    ]
}
```

I tried

```
aws ecs list-services --cluster splat-dev --profile mfa | jq -r '.serviceArns[] | select( . | contains("edp-api-dev")'
```

but get syntax error

Comment: When you have a syntax error, it's good to state what it is exactly. In this case, I get `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')'` which pretty much tells you the problem, that you're missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I forgot the closing parenthesis:

```
aws ecs list-services --cluster splat-dev --profile mfa |
  jq -r '.serviceArns[] | select(contains("edp-api-dev"))'
#                                                       ^
```